# how to call active frame that already exist from another class that extends JDialog then remove all of its component?

Tags: java, swing

I have `class main extends jframe`, it has a button that calls /shows another class that extends `jdialog`.

If the button from `jdialog` is triggered, it will dispose that dialog and will remove all component of `jframe`, then add it to a new `jpanel`.

What should I do?

**Here's my new broken code:**

```
public class mainz extends JFrame{
mainz(){
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    JToolBar r = new JToolBar();
    r.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
    add(r, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    JButton n = new JButton();
    r.add(n, BorderLayout.EAST);

    n.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
            show();
        }
    });
}

public void  show(){
    dialogz d = new dialogz(this);
    d.setVisible(true);
}

public void lastHope(){
    getContentPane().removeAll();
    getContentPane().validate();
    getContentPane().repaint();
}

public static void main (String[]args){
    new mainz().setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
}
```

}

```
public class dialogz extends JDialog{
public dialogz(final mainz owner) {
    setSize(300, 300);
    JButton n = new JButton("execute");
    add(n);

    final JFrame ew = (JFrame)super.getOwner();// <<

    n.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
            dispose();
            //owner.lastHope;
            ew.removeAll();// <<
            ew.validate();// <<
            ew.repaint();// <<
        }
    });
}

void yes(){
    getOwner().removeAll();

    getOwner().validate();
    getOwner().repaint();
}
```

}

I know I can prevent my `main` class from extending `jframe`, and call it from main instead, but I want to do it like that...

Please help me ... T-T

Sorry for my English, I from a far away country ~,~"

update:
the error is

java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.SwingUtilities$SharedOwnerFrame cannot be cast to javax.swing.JFrame

it will be done with delete the line that contain
// <<
then call lastHope();

but i think there's a another way to get that existing jframe to removeall
(by casting it first or something ~,~" )

Comment: removeAll() method is what you seek

Comment: @sgmart: looking briefly at his code above, it looks like he already knows about this method.

Comment: Ok, thanks, that's right. I am working in a solution!

Comment: @Jason: please see edit to my answer regarding `revalidate()` and `repaint()`.

Comment: thankz99x
i just want method to call Jframe(class main extends jframe)that already exist&visible from other class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `getParent()` but you never set the parent (or owner). That should happen in the constructor as already pointed out. Also, be mindful that `getParent()` returns a `Container` object and `getOwner()` returns a `Window` object. Both of these refer to the JFrame which is the parent and owner. If you want to use it as a JFrame, you'll have to cast the output as `(JFrame)`. But `removeAll()` is in `Container` class so if that's all you want, there'll be no need for casting.

**Update**:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JDialog dialog = new JDialog(frame);//frame is owner

JFrame parentOfDialog = (JFrame)(dialog.getParent());
//OR
//JFrame parentOfDialog = (JFrame)(dialog.getOwner());
parentOfDialog.removeAll();
```

If you are using your custom class, pass `JFrame` in the constructor and call `super`.

Please read the javadoc on [JDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html) before you try to use it. Also, read more about inheritance.

Comment: how to casting it than remove all of components??
(im a stupid child that just born ~,~ i dont know java to much)
JFrame e = (JFrame)this.getOwner();
         e.removeAll();
         e.repaint();
         e.validate();
got an error = javax.swing.SwingUtilities$SharedOwnerFrame cannot be cast to javax.swing.JFrame....

if i use getParent() in class dialogz extends Jdialog does it return jdialog it self??  i want it return that existing jframe T-T

Comment: Did you specify an `owner` when you were creating the dialog? Post an updated code (in code format) so that we can help.

Comment: I've posted an update to my response. Most importantly, read more about it before using it.

Comment: thankz dude.. but i still confused how to get that existing jframe... i update my broken code

Comment: `parentOfDialog.removeAll();` could be remove the `RootPane`, last stations is `ContentPane`, never going deeper to the `RootPane`, but in this case this container is very funny and especially translucent forever

Comment: i still got error //final Jframe ew = (Jframe)super.getowner(); how to do this?

Comment: Try `JFrame ew = (JFrame)(super.getOwner());` note: case-sensitivity and bracket casting.

Comment: @davidXYZ ..
still can't remove all...
ew.removeAll(); ew.validate(); ew.repaint();

Comment: thankz dude its help a lot..  just need to get the content pane..
JFrame ew = (Jframe)(super.getOwner()); ew.getContentpane; ew.removeAll(); ew.validate(); ew.repaint(); thanks a lot, arigato, gracias, gamsa-hamnida thankz

Answer (score 2):

I'm not clear on what your goal is, but if you want to change the components that are displayed in a container, such as a JFrame or JDialog's contentPane, then I recommend that you use a [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) to do this since it allows you to easily swap "views".

There could be two ways to do this:

- Your JDialog class could use a reference to the JFrame that is passed in via its constructor (and you should then pass it immediately into the dialog's `super` constructor so that your modality will work correctly). You could then call any public methods in the JFrame's class.
- Or since the JDialog is modal, the JFrame's code will halt while the dialog is visible. You could swap "views" immediately after the dialog has been disposed of and is no longer visible. this would keep the JFrame manipulating code in the JFrame class.
- Edit: note that if you don't use CardLayout, then you're responsible for calling `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on any container who gets its components changed.

As an aside: since English is not your first tongue and nor is it the native language of many folks on this forum, please avoid using non-standard abbreviations. The clearer your communication with us, the easier it will be for us to understand you and help you.

Comment: i kind of person that freak of java reflection if i use card layout...

(i still don't know how, but i believe reflection posible to bring mad to my code if some1 play it in my code)...
anyway i want to use memory a little as can... 

how to use reference of my main class?

//code in dialogz class..
main m = new main();
//or...
main m;
its contain error...

i have been use validate(), revalidate, repaint(), pack() in my post code...
but it still error

im a newbie stupid java programmer..

i just want method to call Jframe(class main extends jframe)that already exist&visible from other class